# How to get dhcp lease expire time with WMI?

Tags: powershell, wmi, dhcp

Now I'm using `Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName 'pc' -ScopeId 'id' -AllLeases` with `$object.leaseExpiryTime` to get lease expiry time.

But is it possible to get it with WMI query? Kindly ask you for example.

Comment: I know about this method: `Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"` but looks like I can't get expiry time with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration), as it does contain `DHCPLeaseExpires`. As for an example,

```
gwmi -query "select DHCPLeaseExpires, ipaddress, Description from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where dhcpleaseexpires is not null"
# Output
Description      : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
DHCPLeaseExpires : 20200604032809.000000+180
IPAddress        : {192.168.1.104, fe80::...}
```

To convert DHCPLeaseExpires into a .Net DateTime, use `ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(String)` from [System.Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.todatetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). A DateTime supports several [formatting strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) like so,

```
$wlan = gwmi -query "select ..."
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Management
$t = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($wlan.DHCPLeaseExpires)
$t.GetType()                                                                            
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType

$t.ToString('u')
2020-06-04 03:28:09Z

$t.ToString('G')                                                                        
4.6.2020 3:28:09
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But what if i got much more parameters then I need? Look, I run `gwmi -ComputerName dhcp -query "select DHCPLeaseExpires from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where DHCPLeaseExpires is not null"` 
and got this output: 
`__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
__SUPERCLASS     :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
DHCPLeaseExpires : 20200603122700.000000+120
PSComputerName`

In your output you got only what you have requested. But I got a lot of extra info. Why?

Comment: I omitted those for brevity. Pipe the results to `Select-Object` and pick whatever you need.

Comment: Could you tell me one more thing, please. What is the format of time - "20200604032809.000000+180"? Any way to compare it with (Get-Date) in any format?